# How to get remaining days from dayjs when getting months

Tags: javascript, angular, dayjs

So I'm having trouble finding a solution to this online, and if there's one thing I hate; it's working with dates.

I need to be able to calculate a person's age in months and days. So if they were born July 3rd, 2020 I need something like `2 months, 21 days`.

I have the code for the months here: `return dayjs(dayjs()).diff(value, 'month');` where value is the date, but am struggling to think of a way to get those days to be accurate.

Anything would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you subtract the the numbers that represent the days in your dates from one another and take the absolute value.

In your example, with the dates July 3rd, 2020 and September 24th, 2020, this would mean doing 3-24 = -21, which would be 21 after taking the absolute value.

Note that your problem is sort of ill-posed. It doesn't really make sense to give someone's age in months, as the amount of days change in a given month. But what you can do is define that x months later just means changing the value of the months in a date. I.e., two months after July 3rd would be September 3rd. This way you can just take whatever difference remains and use this as number of days, as shown above.